# Blogger mobile dynamic views .mobile custom class breaks web template

Tags: web, mobile, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I work on a few blogger dynamic views sites.  In order to use the mobile class you used to replace  with :     in the html.  This allows for css customization.  However now when you make this change, it allows my mobile site to use the styling I've set (like it always did) but it breaks my magazine web template changing it to the 'sidebar' template, which is completely trash for my purposes.

Anyone else notice this or find a work around. I know they're making changes periodically but this seems like a crazy glitch.  I've let blogger know, but that doesn't help me in the mean time.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Changing <body> class to <body expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'> breaks the template.

Comment: Also changing <body> to <body expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass + &quot; &quot; + data:blog.pageType'> In order to style page types, breaks the template.  Adding  setTimeout(function() {, causes the same behaviour, as well as the javascript blogger.templates().compile( 

It seems making any change to html breaks the template. I've duplicated this behaviour across several blogs and it only started happening as recently as two weeks ago.  Can anyone else duplicate this?

Comment: One more very important note to mention.  Also uploading a template that has any of these changes made, now also breaks the template you are trying to upload.    Meaning you can't get this functionality back in your template or continue work on your site, until they fix this !! :(  I've lost two mobile sites because of this, be warned...... And have had to revert to their poorly design, cardboard standard mobile templates, it sucks royally.